# How do I get a unique result from a list using LINQ

Tags: c#

I have a problem with different values. I have problem

```
 List<Program> programs = new List<Program>();
            programs.Add(new Program(1, "R"));
            programs.Add(new Program(1, "R"));
            programs.Add(new Program(1, "R"));
            programs.Add(new Program(1, "S"));
            programs.Add(new Program(1, "S"));
            programs.Add(new Program(2, "S"));
            programs.Add(new Program(2, "S"));
            programs.Add(new Program(2, "S"));
            programs.Add(new Program(3, "K"));
```

And I am trying to use LINQ

```
var query = programs.SelectMany(x => x.id)
                .GroupBy(s => s)
                .Select(g => new { Name = g.Key, Count = g.Count() });
```

To get a result like

| Id | Char | Count |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | R | 3 |
| 1 | S | 2 |
| 2 | S | 3 |
| 3 | K | 1 |

Can you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var query = programs
                .GroupBy(x => new { x.Id, x.Char })
                .Select(g => new { g.Key.Id, g.Key.Char, Count = g.Count() });
```